# How to download and install boost headers only?

Tags: docker, boost, alpine-linux

I am trying to keep my docker builder image as small as possible. As my project requires only boost headers, I wonder if there is a way to install the headers only without installing the whole libboost-dev package with its dependencies?

To keep the builder image as small as possible, I am looking for a solution that avoids cloning the whole boost repository or installing the libboost-dev library with its dependencies.

Is there a way to do this via the package manager or at least a way to download the headers only?

---

*I am using alpine linux and the the apk package manager.*

Comment: You can clone `git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost; cd boost; ./b2 headers`

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I updated my question. I am looking for a way that does not require to download all.

Comment: If you want to keep your docker image as small as possible then use [mukti-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and don't worry about the size of the builder image.